# Android Design Principles?

Tags: gui-design, android, guidelines, design-principles

Hi I am getting started with building Android apps and I think I am getting good at coding, but now I need help with the design. So can you please help me by suggesting any tools or books where I can learn about creating a beautiful UI for Android apps?

Comment: This isn't a site for requesting book recommendations. It is a specific Question and Answer site where a question is posed that is around a specific problem and people then solve that problem by giving the answer to it. Recommendations for products are more suited to a discussion forum than a Q&A site as there is no correct answer to such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of Android you are targeting, you will want to look to different style guides.

Upcoming Android versions will follow [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). Definitely check this out as you go further into developing for Android. Also, check out Android's overall [design guide](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

In brief, Material Design focuses on controlled use of bold colors, intuitive animation, a focus on typography, and, of course, the material metaphor. Check out some examples below.

[image]
[image]